# How to run StatSVN in svn 1.10.2

Tags: statsvn

I have tried to run StatSVN from SVN 1.10.2, and I got the following error. Is there any other way to run in Statsvn in svn 1.10.2?

Could you suggest me?

Oct 04, 2018 6:23:04 PM net.sf.statsvn.util.JavaUtilTaskLogger info
INFO: StatSVN – SVN statistics generation

Oct 04, 2018 6:23:05 PM net.sf.statsvn.util.JavaUtilTaskLogger error
SEVERE: Subversion binary is incorrect version. Found: 1.10.2, required: 1.3.0

Answer (score 4):

On GitHub I found a release StatSVN 0.7.1 fixing this issue:

https://github.com/AusHick/StatSVN/releases/tag/v0.7.1

Does not seem to be official (?) but works.

There was a bug report proposing the solution on offical sites too:

https://sourceforge.net/p/statsvn/bugs/109/

But there was no official reaction or bugfix release.

- https://sourceforge.net/projects/statsvn/
- https://www.statsvn.org/

It seems the StatSVN project is dead.